# When I right-click and copy a query in Access, the query is executed, can this be stopped?

Tags: windows-10, ms-access-2010

In Microsoft Access, when I want to copy-paste a query to make a backup, the database is running the query and putting the result in my clipboard.
This is a definite inconvenience for large queries which take time to run, or queries that perform append/update/delete actions. My workaround has been to open the SQL-view and copy the query from there.

Is this something wrong with Access, Windows 10, or maybe my clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

in the navigation pane - - I can always copy/paste a query object without it running....it is a very common thing to do, so something is wrong.  it will be a matter of isolating the cause.

create a brand new db, with 1 table, make a query - and copy it.... will just take a minute...  see if it runs also.  if so then it is a setting on your pc...  if not then it is unique to that one app.   I don't remember seeing this type feature in the Options area - but look there first...

assuming you have another PC available to you - try things there just to sanity check...

Comment: Thanks for the steps. Yes I am referring to the navigation pane (at left, "All Access Objects"). I've tested creating a new database, and also on an older database to confirm the right-click + copy misbehavior. In trying your suggestions, this also occurred when I copied a table (all records moved to clipboard). I'm able to confirm this on larger tables/queries (more than 65k records), which report "You are trying to copy too many records etc..."

Comment: (comment text limit.)  I have confirmed the behavior on two additional stations, which have the same configuration as my own. I've poked around the options, general and database-specific but I have not found anything relating to copy behavior.

Comment: it's almost like your right click = double click.  definitely we Access developers right click to copy/paste queries frequently, as well as delete or rename... and so a right click definitely does not trigger them to actually open/run.... there has to be an option somewhere; is it possible it is your operating system ??....

Comment: For clarity, when I right click the copy does not happen automatically. The query runs when I choose Copy in the context menu. I wonder if there is anyway for me to confirm the issue is with Access vs Windows. Maybe there is another application with complex objects. I might also make the leap and update my Win10 Build from 19-09, I haven't gone to v20-04 yet.

Comment: in access - go to File tab then Options  
then select 'Current Database'
then select 'Navigation Options'
look to see in the 'Open Objects with' box....mine is always set at double-click

Comment: Mine is the same. The radio option on the right. Thanks again for slogging through this with me!

Comment: I've updated my Windows 10 to 2004, but this issue persists.

Comment: is there a Windows option as to the behavior of right click - in being a double click?

Comment: I have not noticed anything unusual occurring related to my clicks. The right-click opens the context menu, I choose the Copy option.
What I expect to happen is the query or table metadata should be put into my clipboard. 
However, what does happen is the query runs and the results are put into my clipboard.

Comment: yeah so a double click runs a query ; while a right click should offer options - such as open in Design View, copy, etc.     that's normal behavior.  it seems like your right click is being actioned as a double click....  can't say why that is....

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me, could not fix the running problem, but found very good workaround.

Copy the SQL command to a new query.

1. In the "All Access Objects Pane" right click the desired query and open it in Design mode;
2. In the menu "View" option , change the view to "SQL view" (usually at the top left;
3. copy the SQL code (Ctrl + C);
4. Go to the "Create", "Queries" section and Click on "Query Design";
5. (if you need) Enter in SQL View and paste the code.

Should achieve the functionality you seek.
Good luck.